# Shopify find order ID in hook

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I need to connect some external service to the Shopify store. I've set up the hook on `Order creation` event, I can receive it but I didn't find information about what incoming data means. I mean I need to store `order_id` in order to be able to control it. I'm receiving test hook that contains field named `order_number`. Can anyone confirm that this field is exact order ID? Also I'm receiving in the hook `id` field but I guess that field is `hook_id`, not `order_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you already created webhook for `Order creation` then when order will be created, you will receive JSON with order object. This object has `id` property

Example of this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 820982911946154500,
    "email": "jon@doe.ca",
    "closed_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-11-29T05:57:26-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-29T05:57:26-05:00",
    "number": 234,
    "note": null,
    "token": "123456abcd",
    "gateway": null,
    "test": true,
    "total_price": "793.50",
    "subtotal_price": "783.50",
    "total_weight": 0,
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "taxes_included": false,
    "currency": "USD",
    "financial_status": "voided",
    "confirmed": false,
    "total_discounts": "5.00",
    "total_line_items_price": "788.50",
    "cart_token": null,
    "buyer_accepts_marketing": true,
    "name": "#9999",
    "referring_site": null,
    "landing_site": null,
    "cancelled_at": "2017-11-29T05:57:26-05:00",
    "cancel_reason": "customer",
    "total_price_usd": null,
    "checkout_token": null,
    "reference": null,
    "user_id": null,
    "location_id": null,
    "source_identifier": null,
    "source_url": null,
    "processed_at": null,
    "device_id": null,
    "phone": null,
    "customer_locale": "en",
    "app_id": null,
    "browser_ip": null,
    "landing_site_ref": null,
    "order_number": 1234,
    "discount_codes": [],
    "note_attributes": [],
    "payment_gateway_names": [
        "visa",
        "bogus"
    ],
    "processing_method": "",
    "checkout_id": null,
    "source_name": "web",
    "fulfillment_status": "pending",
    "tax_lines": [],
    "tags": "",
    "contact_email": "jon@doe.ca",
    "order_status_url": "https://checkout.shopify.com/24877298/orders/123456abcd/authenticate?key=abcdefg",
    "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 866550311766439000,
            "variant_id": null,
            "title": "Test Product Discount",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": "99.50",
            "grams": 0,
            "sku": "",
            "variant_title": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "product_id": 252236300325,
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": true,
            "gift_card": false,
            "name": "Test Product Discount",
            "variant_inventory_management": null,
            "properties": [],
            "product_exists": true,
            "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
            "total_discount": "0.00",
            "fulfillment_status": null,
            "tax_lines": []
        },
        {
            "id": 141249953214522980,
            "variant_id": null,
            "title": "ABSTRACT PENDANT, MULTI-COLOURED, ROSE GOLD PLATING",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": "689.00",
            "grams": 100,
            "sku": "030711585240",
            "variant_title": null,
            "vendor": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "product_id": 252560506917,
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": true,
            "gift_card": false,
            "name": "ABSTRACT PENDANT, MULTI-COLOURED, ROSE GOLD PLATING",
            "variant_inventory_management": null,
            "properties": [],
            "product_exists": true,
            "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
            "total_discount": "5.00",
            "fulfillment_status": null,
            "tax_lines": []
        }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
        {
            "id": 271878346596884000,
            "title": "Generic Shipping",
            "price": "10.00",
            "code": null,
            "source": "shopify",
            "phone": null,
            "requested_fulfillment_service_id": null,
            "delivery_category": null,
            "carrier_identifier": null,
            "discounted_price": "10.00",
            "tax_lines": []
        }
    ],
    "billing_address": {
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "address1": "123 Billing Street",
        "phone": "555-555-BILL",
        "city": "Billtown",
        "zip": "K2P0B0",
        "province": "Kentucky",
        "country": "United States",
        "last_name": "Biller",
        "address2": null,
        "company": "My Company",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name": "Bob Biller",
        "country_code": "US",
        "province_code": "KY"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "address1": "123 Shipping Street",
        "phone": "555-555-SHIP",
        "city": "Shippington",
        "zip": "40003",
        "province": "Kentucky",
        "country": "United States",
        "last_name": "Shipper",
        "address2": null,
        "company": "Shipping Company",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name": "Steve Shipper",
        "country_code": "US",
        "province_code": "KY"
    },
    "fulfillments": [],
    "refunds": [],
    "customer": {
        "id": 115310627314723950,
        "email": "john@test.com",
        "accepts_marketing": false,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "orders_count": 0,
        "state": "disabled",
        "total_spent": "0.00",
        "last_order_id": null,
        "note": null,
        "verified_email": true,
        "multipass_identifier": null,
        "tax_exempt": false,
        "phone": null,
        "tags": "",
        "last_order_name": null,
        "default_address": {
            "id": 715243470612851200,
            "customer_id": 115310627314723950,
            "first_name": null,
            "last_name": null,
            "company": null,
            "address1": "123 Elm St.",
            "address2": null,
            "city": "Ottawa",
            "province": "Ontario",
            "country": "Canada",
            "zip": "K2H7A8",
            "phone": "123-123-1234",
            "name": "",
            "province_code": "ON",
            "country_code": "CA",
            "country_name": "Canada",
            "default": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm receiving exact what you provided. So "820982911946154500" is order_id in your case right? I thought that this is a hook_id

Comment: It is an order ID